# Deployment with Nextjs and themed semantic-ui

Tags: reactjs, deployment, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, next.js

I am using `nextjs` framework and as UI framework I have chosen `semantic-ui` accompanied with `semantic-ui-react`.

The main reason for me choosing `semantic-ui` is the theming power of the framework.

- I have installed the full package of `semantic-ui` as it being showed [here](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html). 
  `
- `semantic.json` file has the following:

  `{
    "base": "/client/static/semantic",
    "paths": {
      "source": {
        "config": "src/theme.config",
        "definitions": "src/definitions/",
        "site": "src/site/",
        "themes": "src/themes/"
      },
      "output": {
        "packaged": "dist/",
        "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
        "compressed": "dist/components/",
        "themes": "dist/themes/"
      },
      "clean": "dist/"
    },
    "permission": false,
    "autoInstall": false,
    "rtl": false,
    "components": [blah blah],
    "version": "2.2.10"
  }`

Theming is working properly on localhost.

The problem is the following: when trying to deploy usin `now` dependencies are being installed and `semantic-ui` feels like it is not there. That means there is no styling at all.

I am including semantic folder to my project (meaning, I am now gitignoring the `/client/static/semantic` folder).

What is the right way to deploy using `Nextjs` and `semantic-ui`?

**UPDATE:

Found where the problem comes from but still dont know how to solve it.

So the proccess goes like that when you theme your semantic-ui.

1. You install `semantic-ui` .
2. `semantic-ui` looks for the file `semantic.json` and knows you are theming.
3. Files and folder for theming are being created BUT not build. That means in order for the compoments of `semantic-ui` to be build it is needed to navigate to the specific `semantic` folder and run `gulp build`.

The problem is `now` dont know how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using `next build` and `next start` locally? you should have all your assets built before running `next build` to bundle everything up.

Comment: Let me put it like this. 

When I am cloning the repo and `npm install` and then `npm run dev` it is like `semantic-ui` is not there. When I go and `gulp build` into semantic then theming works fine.

What I try to say is that `now` is doing the same but needs somehow the `gulp build` for semantic to be triggered

Comment: you could setup a build process in the `package.json` file in the scripts where it says `"build": "next build"` change it so it does what you want for example: `"build": "gulp build && next build"`

Comment: @JohhanSantana this worked like a charm ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to close this with an answer from the comments.

In order to get pre-builds such as gulp/grunt/etc before the actual `next build` you have to create a script which does what you want.

**Example:**

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build && next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

and just run `npm run build` to have your building process started.